# Maven's Non-Resolvable Parent POM Problem

Tags: maven, cumulocity

We have downloaded the Project "https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-clients-java/src/develop/" and try to run the project the project but we have the following issue :

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java:clients-java:9.19.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.nsn.cumulocity.root:root:pom:9.19.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java:clients-java:9.19.1-SNAPSHOT (D:\Projects\Dormakaba\Code\Test-Code\cumulocity\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java:clients-java:9.19.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.nsn.cumulocity.root:root:pom:9.19.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

My Main POM.XML

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.nsn.cumulocity.root</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>9.19.0</version>
    <relativePath>/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>com.nsn.cumulocity.clients-java</groupId>
<artifactId>clients-java</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>9.19.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Cumulocity :: Clients Java</name>
<url>http://startups.jira.com/wiki/display/MTM/Home</url>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:hg:ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-clients-java</connection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<modules>
    <module>device-capability-model</module>
    <module>java-client</module>
    <module>java-me-client</module>
    <module>java-me-client-test</module>
    <module>java-me-maven-plugin</module>
    <module>java-me-smartrest</module>      
    <module>java-email-client</module>
    <module>java-sms-client</module>
    <module>java-client-services</module>
</modules>
```

...................

Best regards, Manoj

Comment: The given parent `com.nsn.cumulocity.root` does not exist in central. So you have to configure the appropriate repository where it's coming from ...furthermore remove `</relativePath>` from your pom file...

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message states, your Parent Pom is not found in the Remote Repository and neither in your local Repository nor in the given relative Path.
Put the Parent Pom in the correct location and all should be fine.

EDIT: The description of this project states, that you do need to add their own repo.

https://bitbucket.org/m2m/cumulocity-clients-java